# Use typescript in AngularJS to check the interpolation/binding in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I know that TypeScript can detect compile errors for *.ts files.

However, what about getting these benefits in AngularJS views/templates? For example, if I have a code like:

```
<div ng-controller="HomeController as home">
    {{home.property1}}
</div>
```

And I have a HomeController class defined, then I'd like to receive a compile error if "property1" isn't defined for HomeController class.

Is anything like that possible?

Comment: Aurelia framework ( http://aurelia.io, similar to Angular 2, but less boilerplate) has it: https://github.com/MeirionHughes/aurelia-template-lint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is anything like that possible?

Possible : Yes. You will need to create your own HTML Parser and then integrate it with the TypeScript compiler (possibly using the TypeScript language service).

Existing : No.

Comment: I'll take it to their github then :). Thanks