# Can I use Typescript to validate an AngularJS view expression?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm using typescript for my AngularJS controllers and services.  I love being able to compile the JS, since it saves a ton of troubleshooting time and drastically improves intellisense.  But what it doesn't catch are the typos left in the views.  If I have a typed model property called "customerName", and in a view I reference `{{ x.customerNam }}`, I don't find out about the mistake until run-time.

Does anyone know how I can use Typescript to also validate my views?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use typescript in AngularJS to check the interpolation/binding in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25140029/use-typescript-in-angularjs-to-check-the-interpolation-binding-in-html)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use typescript for the views unfortunately. Your IDE tooling will have to be your helper here. I know they are improving Angular support in the next update for VS 2013 and VS 2014 should also have much better support.

> We’re also looking into improving the Angular and Bootstrap story
>   significantly in Visual Studio, both supporting the current versions
>   but also making sure that Angular 2.0 is fully supported with
>   Intellisense etc. It’s a big task. In Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 we
>   already made modifications to improve the Angular experience. The HTML
>   editor no longer complains about custom elements and attributes and
>   the {{}} templating support has been reimplemented to be more
>   flexible.

[AngularJs Updates in VS 2013 Update 4 / 2014](http://madskristensen.net/post/fall-update-2014---my-year-in-review)

WebStorm 9 just released which might have better view support as well for helping to find typos.

Web Essentials is also updated often and might have better view support in the future.

http://vswebessentials.com/changelog

Comment: as @John mentioned [WebStorm][1] does help with the binding expressions, 
do not expect XAML/Resharper like experience , but its quite good
nothing to do with TypeScript tho...
  [1]: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/